# Empty String is inserted as null in the MySQL DB from the view

Tags: java, mysql, spring, ibatis

I have two different DB servers, one for testing and one for production.

I have a table and it has 'datetime' type column in mysql.

In a view page, the column value is set to '' which means an empty-string.

When I try to update the table, it is converted to null in testing environment.
However, it is just ''(java.lang.String) in real environment.

Two different servers have mostly similar my.cnf

Config.xml files are the same about mysql.

Comment: Wut u sayin man... :P :D

Answer (score 2):

An empty DateTime object is treated like a null in MySQL.
Only if your column type is nvarchar, empty string and null makes sense.

'' is treated like a null but ' ' is not treated like a null.
Put the java code from where you are making an insert call.

Comment: I found another solution.
As I know, oracle processes '' as null but mysql does not.
So, I added PropertyEditorRegistry in servelt-context.xml. 
It has a function which makes en empty string to null so I used the function.
Thanks anyway :)